# issue of default frame_id for velodyne_pointcloud/Transform2

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing loading a pcap file and transform velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan into /velodyne/pointcloud2, and that the converted pointcloud2 data looks not right. And I think that this is caused by the default frame_id setting.

By default, the frame_id of velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan is "velodyne" and the frame_id for /velodyne/pointcloud2 is "odom", and here is my launch file,

---

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="velodyne_broadcaster" 
        args="0 0 2 0 0 0 base velodyne 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_broadcaster"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_broadcaster"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" />

  <node pkg="velodyne_common" type="read" name="read" 
        args="-f $(find velodyne_common)/../velodyne_data_01/unit_46_Monterey_subset.pcap" >
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="velodyne" />
  </node>

  <!-- start nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="velodyne_nodelet_manager" 
        args="manager" />

  <!--transform velodyne/packets into pointcloud2 via nodelet -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="transform2" 
        args="load velodyne_pointcloud/Transform2 velodyne_nodelet_manager" > 
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" />

</launch>
```

---

The original data coordinates are relative to the velodyne frame, yet the converted pointcloud2 shifted down (2 meters, in this case) from the velodyne frame. Then I have to respecify the frame_id for pointcloud2 to "velodyne" in order to locate the resultant pointcloud2 correctly.

So my feeling is that the above default frame_id looks not so reasonable, since typically there is a determinate tf tree in the scenario and the pointcloud2 should not be remapped arbitrarily to a frame other than the default value "velodyne". Correct me if I am wrong.

clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27732/issue-of-default-frame_id-for-velodyne_pointcloud/transform2/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `velodyne_pointcloud` package is currently in active development. We hope to release a complete version soon, but until then you should only use it experimentally.

As part of this redesign, the `velodyne_common` package will soon be *deprecated*. If you want to try the new, experimental packages, there is a driver nodelet that goes with `velodyne_pointcloud` (start the nodelet manager first):

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="driver_nodelet"
      args="load velodyne_driver/DriverNodelet velodyne_nodelet_manager" />
```

There is currently an active [design review](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne/Reviews/2012-02-02_API_Review) for the `velodyne` stack. Please sign up and contribute your ideas and suggestions.

EDIT:

The main purpose of the transform nodelet is transforming data from a moving device into some stationary coordinate frame. The Velodyne turns at 10Hz, so the vehicle can move far enough to affect registration during a compete revolution. [REP-0105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) recommends the `/odom` frame for that purpose. Since your needs may vary, the `frame_id` parameter is provided.

If you just want the data converted to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` in the `/velodyne` frame, the `velodyne_pointcloud/Cloud2Nodelet` should suffice.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1